# reinstecken vs. reintun

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ich höre oft die Worte *reintun* und *reinstecken*. Ich kenne die Bedeutungen von beiden aber ich kann den genauen Unterschied nicht begreifen. Könntet Ihr ihn mir erklären?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Reintun" ist das allgemeinere Verb: man tut irgendetwas, und danach ist irgendetwas irgendwo drin.

Genauere Verben, die alle unter den Oberbegriff "reintun" fallen, sind z.B.:

reinstecken: Man *steckt* etwas irgendwo *rein*, wo es dann *steckt.*
reinstellen: Man *stellt* etwas irgendwo *rein*, wo es dann *steht.*
reinlegen: Man *legt* etwas irgendwo *rein*, wo es dann *liegt.*
reinschrauben, reinheben, reindrücken: dazu muss man jeweils das tun, was in dem Verb steht, damit danach etwas irgendwo drin ist.

Die Vorsilbe "rein" ist natürlich Umgangssprache für "herein" oder "hinein", bei diesen Verben meistens für "hinein".